# How can I change the scope using control method of a Controller in ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In ExtJS with control() method of Ext.app.Controller class I can add listeners to components selected via Ext.ComponentQuery inside controller's init() method.

Doing so by default I have the controller scope inside my handler functions. Is there a way to specify some other scope here?

For example in this case:

```
Ext.define('BackOffice.controller.BaseList', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [
        // some refs
    ],

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'bo-list-view > toolbar > button[action=create-new]': {
                click: this.onCreateNewClick
            },

            'bo-list-view > toolbar > button[action=edit]': {
                click: this.onEditClick
            },

            'bo-list-view > toolbar > button[action=refresh]': {
                click: this.onRefreshClick
            }
        })
    },

    // ...
});
```

In handler functions I want to know the exact buttons clicked to perform some actions based on this information.

I've tried specifying scope within button declaration via scope field, this doesn't help.

Also I wanted to use Ext.bind() to solve the issue, but to bind the function to I need some reference to the button again.

Using .on() to add listeners doesn't work in init() because it's called before application's launch method.

Is there any way to add listeners to this buttons from controller saving the scope?

**Update**

The reference to the button is passed as the first argument into the handler function.
This solves my problem, but still looking for a way to define the scope inside control() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at description of the `click` event: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-event-click you will see that very first arguments will be pointer to the button, i.e. you don't need to change the scope - just declare arguments in your function and you will know which button was pressed.

Comment: Ahh this () what a shame, I've quick-edited the code at the last moment and missed it, thanks for mentioning will fix sample.

Comment: Regarding adding "scope: this", that doesn't work in case of control() method, it says that I can specify only handlers there.

Using first argument works in this case for buttons, but doesn't for some custom third-party components without this feature, so I still have the issue

Comment: I definitely use `scope: this` in a lot of my controllers. But actually do this to bring scope back to the controller class. If you want to specify certain button as a scope - how do you even detect what element you need? You're accessing it using refs.

Comment: You are right, I think setting scope to the component itself in this case isn't such a good idea. I think I will try to re-implement other components custom event firing to them. Then I'll be able to use it from first argument as in case of button.

Can you please edit your answer leaving only the last part with first argument suggestion then it will be more relevant to question and I'll be able to accept it, thanks!

Comment: That's be the best approach. You should not try to pass along pointers to something when component should let know handler this information.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve more advanced scope functionality by using a configuration object.

```
Ext.define('BackOffice.controller.BaseList', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [
        // some refs
    ],

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'bo-list-view > toolbar > button[action=create-new]': {
                // This will call onCreateNewClick with global window as the scope
                click: {fn: this.onCreateNewClick, scope: window}
            },

            'bo-list-view > toolbar > button[action=edit]': {
                click: {fn: this.onEditClick, scope: otherScopeObj}
            },

            'bo-list-view > toolbar > button[action=refresh]': {
                click: this.onRefreshClick
            }
        });
    },

    // ...
});
```

I don't know if all the normal configs work (i.e. single: true) but scope does.